# CUstom Alarm used to stop ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am using CloudWatch alarm to stop ec2 instance. For my case I am pushing log information from my ec2 instance to CloudWatch via log grope. And I filter those information via filter with specific pattern that detect error messages due to failed authentication.  Unlike standard ways to stop ec2 instance using CPU utilization. I am using a custom metric (figure). Then I am configuring the action to stop the ec2 instance (figure).

But my alarm appears with state "Insufficient data" all the time. can any one help me to solve the problem and stop my ec2 instance once it is in alarm (means that the logs match the pattern of the filter), Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: You should be able to configure how cloudwatch alarms treat missing data: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: It is simply indicating that data has not been pushed to CloudWatch within the desired period (5 minutes). This might be because your custom metric is only sent when it is non-zero. It shouldn't impact things, so if the alarm works as expected, then do not worry about this message.

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to see any action because the alarm is not triggered. If I create an alarm based on specific metrics ( for exp: if log masseges matched the pattern I am using for 3 times ==> launch the Alarm, behind that i send emails via SNS ) IT work correctly. Once I modify the Alarm and I add the Action "Stop" to that same alarm process functioning before, it failed and move to the state Insufficient data. Even if the pattern is matched for more than 3 times Idon't get any alarm not emails sent and the ec2 instance stay up